# Azure CLI commands not working from Bamboo task

Tags: azure, powershell, bamboo, azure-cli

I have a .ps1 file where I have written the Azure CLI script to login into azure using service principal.It looks as below.

```
write-host 'Login start'
#parameters 
$applicationId = $args[0].toString()
$securePasswordSP = $args[1].toString()
$tenantId = $args[2].toString()

$adminSecurePassword = $securePasswordSP | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
az login --service-principal --username $applicationId --password $adminSecurePassword --tenant $tenantId

write-host 'Login end'
```

This file is placed in "C:\Test" path. So I open the powershell to execute this file. I run the following command.

```
$SpId = "Service principal Id"
$SpSecret = "Sp Secret"
$tenantId =  "Tenant Id"
& "C:\Test\TestScript.ps1" $SpId $SpSecret $tenantId
```

This works exactly as expected and I'm able to login into Azure account.
But when I use the same command to run from Bamboo,it is not working.In Bamboo, I have added a stage -> Job. In this Job, I have added a task. I have selected the following:

```
Task Type : Script Configuration
Interpreter : Windows Powershell
Script location : Inline
Script Body : 

$SpId = "Service principal Id"
$SpSecret = "Sp Secret"
$tenantId =  "Tenant Id"
& "C:\Test\TestScript.ps1" $SpId $SpSecret $tenantId
```

When I run this Job, I'm getting the following error.

```
az : The term 'az' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

When I directly open windows powershell in bamboo agent and run the same commands, it is working. But when I run the same commands from Bamboo portal, it is failing. Is there any additional step which has to be done which I'm missing.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where the Bamboo and what is the environment of the Bamboo?

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT It is a azure VM , windows server 2016 , if that is what you are asking

Comment: Also, just a note, rest all powershell scripts are running fine from Bamboo portal. Its just Azure CLI cmdlets are not getting executed as explained in the question

Comment: Do you make sure if the Azure CLI installed in the VM?

Comment: Yes, it is installed. That's why when I run the same script directly on powershell , it is running.

Comment: You can check the permission or identity when you execute the scripton Bamboo portal.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT How can I check the permission or identity?